# Android - JNI//NDK Failed to locate SIGSEV

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have NDK C++ code, that produce SIGSEGV error. I am unable to track it down. Custom signal handling returns empty stack trace.

If I catch the error in Android Studio debugger, I got this trace:

**Thread 93 - RxNewThreadSche**

```
void std::__1::__tree_remove<std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*>(std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*, std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*) 0x00000000f0ae86ea
art::gc::allocator::RosAlloc::RefillRun(art::Thread*, unsigned int) 0x00000000f0ae2174
art::gc::allocator::RosAlloc::AllocFromRun(art::Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*) 0x00000000f0ae22de
art::mirror::Object* art::gc::Heap::AllocObjectWithAllocator<true, true, art::mirror::SetLengthVisitor>(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Class*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType, art::mirror::SetLengthVisitor const&) 0x00000000f0a8f086
art::mirror::ObjectArray<art::mirror::Object*>::Alloc(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Class*, int, art::gc::AllocatorType) 0x00000000f0bc1fe0
art::Array_createObjectArray(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jclass*, int) 0x00000000f0c44af0
java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Array.createObjectArray(java.lang.Class, int) 0x000000007229d5d2
```

None of the code is "mine". Only "familiar" is the first line, but I dont know where to find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it was related to this or not...

I had in code:

```
env->NewObjectArray(size, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL)
```

After replace with

```
env->NewObjectArray(size, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), env->NewStringUTF(""))
```

error is not thrown